# Tomcat @Resource annotations API annotation stops working in Tomcat 7

Tags: jsf, tomcat, annotations, tomcat6, tomcat7

I have been using Tomcat 6.0.26-6.0.35 for several years with JSF 2 Mojarra, various versions up to 2.1.2 which I have been using for some months. I have several request-scoped and session-scoped beans with code like this:

```
private @Resource(name="jdbc/cLabs", mappedName="jdbc/cLabs") DataSource cLabs;
```

which has been correctly injected in every version of Tomcat 6 I've used. I also have other types of `@Resource` that doesn't work either, so it isn't just `DataSource resources.` I've tried switching to Tomcat 7.0.27 and suddenly none of these constructs works any more. The resource is not injected. I also have other types of `@Resource` that doesn't work either, so it isn't just `DataSource` resources. However in each case the resource named does exist, and can be looked up via e.g.

```
new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/cLabs");
```

[They are defined by  elements in context.xml]

This of course is a royal PITA as I spent some time a year or two ago replacing the latter with the former. Is there some other magic spell I have to weave with Tomcat 7 to make it work again?

Note that resources *are* injected correctly into Servlets, so it isn't completely broken. Some interaction between Tomcat and JSF.

Comment: Try to add to your `web.xml` this record <resource-ref> <res-ref-name>jdbc/cLabs</res-ref-name> <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type> <res-auth>yourAuth</res-auth> </resource-ref> It has something to do with version of Servlet (you've probably switched to version 3 from 2.5 which is causing this bug)

Comment: I have that already. I haven't changed any versions in web.xml although Tomcat 7 is certainly Servlet 3 where 6 was Servlet 2.5: however @Resource is not part of the Servlet Specification at all so that's not relevant. I will restate that the resource definition itself is working, as shown by the success of the JNDI lookups. It is the *injection* via the `@Resource` annotation that isn't happening.

Comment: @Resource _is_ part of Servlet API starting from version 2.5

Comment: @MatthiasHryniszak Well there you go, so switching between 2.5 and 3 wouldn't do that, not that I did it anyway.

Comment: Having a similar issue, just migrated from tomcat 6 to tomcat 7 and my WebServiceContext is no longer being injected via the `@Resource` annotation.  Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @JohnLeehey Yes, finally, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question, an improved version of @JeffE's answer. The basic problem is:

1. A `Tomcat6InjectionProvider` was provided with JSF 2.0 but was removed at some point.
2. The default `WebContainerInjectionProvider` doesn't process @Resource annotations, as JeffE points out.

You can overcome this without `web.xml` context-entries as follows:

1. Create a file called `META-INF/services/com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider` and add the following line to it:

   ```
   com.sun.faces.vendor.Tomcat7InjectionProvider:org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager
   ```

   The meaning of this line is that if the second class is present in the deployment, the first class is used as the injection provider. The second class above is part of Tomcat 7.
2. Compile the following class.

This version contains numerous improvements over JeffE's version. Specifically:

- it processes superclasses, as required by the `@Resource` and `@Resources` Javadoc
- it processes `@Resource` and `@Resources` annotations at the class level
- it processes methods annotated with `@Resource`, as required by the `@Resource` Javadoc
- it handles empty or missing `name` attributes of `@Resource`s correctly, as required by the `@Resource` Javadoc
- it restores the `Field`'s original access
- it has no dependencies on Tomcat classes.

Adjust the package name above if you change its package name.

```
package com.sun.faces.vendor;

import com.sun.faces.spi.DiscoverableInjectionProvider;
import com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

/**
 * @author Jeff E
 * @author Esmond Pitt Improvements named above.
 * 
 * @see javax.annotation.Resource
 *
 * @see <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a/21978577/207421">This StackOverflow
 * answer, although what org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection may be and where
 * it lives remains a mystery.</a>
 */
public class Tomcat7InjectionProvider
    extends DiscoverableInjectionProvider
{
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
    private ServletContext  servletContext;

    private WebContainerInjectionProvider   delegate = new WebContainerInjectionProvider();

    public Tomcat7InjectionProvider(ServletContext servletContext)
    {
        logger.config("constructed");
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void inject(Object managedBean) throws InjectionProviderException
    {
        logger.log(Level.CONFIG, "managedBean={0}", new Object[]{managedBean.getClass().getName()});
        Class<?> clazz = managedBean.getClass();
        do
        {
            List<Resource>  classResources = new LinkedList<>();
            // Process class-level @Resources and @Resource
            if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(Resources.class))
            {
                Resources annotation = clazz.getAnnotation(Resources.class);
                for (Resource resource : annotation.value())
                {
                    classResources.add(resource);
                }
            }
            if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(Resource.class))
            {
                Resource    annotation = clazz.getAnnotation(Resource.class);
                classResources.add(annotation);
            }
            for (Resource annotation : classResources)
            {
                String  name = annotation.name();
                // Make sure the resource exists.
                try
                {
                    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
                    Object resource = ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/" + name);
                }
                catch (NamingException exc)
                {
                    throw new InjectionProviderException("checking class resource " + annotation.name()+" of "+clazz.getName(), exc);
                }
            }
            // Process fields with @Resource
            // see org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager
//            Field[] fields = Introspection.getDeclaredFields(managedBean.getClass());
            Field[] fields = managedBean.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field : fields)
            {
                if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Resource.class))
                {
                    Resource annotation = field.getAnnotation(Resource.class);
                    String name = annotation.name();
                    logger.log(Level.CONFIG, "injecting @Resource(name=\"{2}\") into {0}.{1}", new Object[]
                        {
                            managedBean.getClass().getName(), field.getName(), name
                        });
                    try
                    {
                        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
                        Object resource;
                        if (name != null && name.length() > 0)
                        {
                            resource = ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/" + name);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            resource = ctx.lookup(clazz.getName() + "/" + field.getName());
                        }
                        // field may be private
                        boolean accessibility = field.isAccessible();
                        try
                        {
                            field.setAccessible(true);
                            field.set(managedBean, resource);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            field.setAccessible(accessibility);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (NamingException | IllegalAccessException exc)
                    {
                        throw new InjectionProviderException("injecting resource " + annotation.name()+" into "+clazz.getName()+"."+field.getName(), exc);
                    }
                }
            }
            // Process methods with @Resource
            for (Method method : clazz.getDeclaredMethods())
            {
                if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Resource.class)
                && method.getName().startsWith("set")
                && method.getName().length() > 3
                && method.getReturnType() == void.class
                && method.getParameterTypes().length == 1)
                {
                    // It's a setter with @Resource
                    Resource annotation = method.getAnnotation(Resource.class);
                    String name = annotation.name();
                    logger.log(Level.CONFIG, "injecting @Resource(name=\"{2}\") via {0}.{1}", new Object[]
                        {
                            managedBean.getClass().getName(), method.getName(), name
                        });
                    try
                    {
                        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
                        Object resource;
                        if (name != null && name.length() > 0)
                        {
                            resource = ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/" + name);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            name = method.getName().substring(3);
                            name = name.substring(0,1).toLowerCase()+name.substring(1);
                            resource = ctx.lookup(clazz.getName() + "/" + name);
                        }
                        // method may be private
                        boolean accessibility = method.isAccessible();
                        try
                        {
                            method.setAccessible(true);
                            method.invoke(managedBean, resource);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            method.setAccessible(accessibility);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (NamingException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException exc)
                    {
                        throw new InjectionProviderException("injecting resource " + annotation.name()+" via "+clazz.getName()+"."+method.getName(), exc);
                    }
                }
            }
        } while ((clazz = clazz.getSuperclass()) != Object.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void invokePostConstruct(Object managedBean) throws InjectionProviderException
    {
        logger.log(Level.CONFIG, "managedBean={0}", new Object[]{managedBean});
        delegate.invokePostConstruct(managedBean);
    }

    @Override
    public void invokePreDestroy(Object managedBean) throws InjectionProviderException
    {
        logger.log(Level.CONFIG, "managedBean={0}", new Object[]{managedBean});
        delegate.invokePreDestroy(managedBean);
    }
}
```

E&OE

Answer (score 3):

My guess is something is causing org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager to ignore annotations because faces requires the @PostConstruct method to be processed apart from @Resource fields.  I have created a workaround that works for fields annotated with @Resource.

Add the following to web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.injectionProvider</param-name>
    <param-value>com.example.faces.Tomcat7InjectionProvider</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And add the class to your source:

```
package com.example.faces;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection;

import com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException;
import com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider;

public class Tomcat7InjectionProvider extends WebContainerInjectionProvider {

    public Tomcat7InjectionProvider(ServletContext servletContext) {
    }

    @Override
    public void inject(Object managedBean) throws InjectionProviderException {
        if (managedBean != null) {
            // see org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager
            Field[] fields = Introspection.getDeclaredFields(managedBean.getClass());
            for (Field field : fields) {
                // field may be private
                field.setAccessible(true);
                if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Resource.class)) {
                    Resource annotation = null;
                    try {
                        annotation = field.getAnnotation(Resource.class);
                        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
                        Object resource = ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/" + annotation.name());
                        field.set(managedBean, resource);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new InjectionProviderException("cannot find resource " + annotation.name(), e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I shouldn't have to do any of that. It's supposed to work out of the box.

Comment: I agree that I would expect it to work out of the box, but so far I have been running fine with my answer. After some debugging, I have found that DefaultInstanceManager only manages classes in web.xml.  The FacesServlet is using (in my case) com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder which will use WebContainerInjectionProvider by default.  The issue is WebContainerInjectionProvider does not process @Resource attributes.

Comment: @EJP - Getting back late and I see you found the answer.  Mojarra 2.2.7 did not include the `Tomcat7InjectionProvider` but still has a `Tomcat6InjectionProvider` which is what I based my class upon.  I haven't found the mechanism to activate one or the other, but the same version of Mojarra will process @Resource in Tomcat6 but not in Tomcat7.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility, yet I would think unlikely; is you are using `metadata-complete="true"` in your web.xml or web-fragment.xml file(s).

Defined metadata-complete:
The metadata-complete attribute defines whether this deployment descriptor and other related deployment 
 descriptors for this module (e.g., web service descriptors) are complete, or whether the class files available 
 to this module and packaged with this application should be examined for annotations that specify 
 deployment information. If metadata-complete is set to "true", the deployment tool must ignore any 
 annotations that specify deployment information, which might be present in the class files of the 
 application. If metadata-complete is not specified or is set to "false", the deployment tool must examine the 
 class files of the application for annotations, as specified by the specifications.

Example web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app metadata-complete="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>ResourceTest</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I'm unable to comment due to rep or I would of asked for more clarification on what errors/etc you are seeing. That being said I have tested with both Tomcat 7.0.27 and Tomcat 7.0.41 with java full version "1.6.0_51-b11-457" and was able to use @Resource.

Context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
  <Resource name="jdbc/Sample" auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource" username="nbuser" password="nbuser"
      driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" 
      url="jdbc:derby://localhost/Sample"
      maxActive="8" maxIdle="4"/>
</Context>
```

ResourceTest.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@WebServlet("/ResourceTest")
public class ResourceTest extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Resource(name="jdbc/Sample")
  private DataSource ds;


public ResourceTest() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<body>");


    try {
        //Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
        //Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
        //DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/Sample");
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        Statement s = conn.createStatement();
        s.execute("Select * From \"NBUSER\".\"Friends\"");
        ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
        while (rs.next()) {
            out.println(rs.getString("NAME") + " is my friend.");
        }
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    out.println("</body>");

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

Comment: What I am seeing is what I said above. "The resource is not injected."

Comment: And I also said *request-scoped and session-scoped beans.* This is a Servlet.