# JSF 2.1 web-app runs on Tomcat 6 but fails on Tomcat 7

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tomcat6, tomcat7

I have a JSF 2.1 web-application that uses Primefaces 3.1.1. The integration-tests run fine on Tomcat 6, but on an identically configured Tomcat 7 I get the following error:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 16.10.2012 15:25:13 com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback visit
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

No further stacktrace or anything that could hint at the problem (all logging levels set to `ALL`). I can load the application in the browser, but it does not respond to any input.

I am using Primefaces 3.1.1 and Mojorra 2.1.13. Is this a known issue? What has changed from Tomcat 6 to 7 that could have this effect?

P.S.: I have also tried JBOSS AS 7 with the built-in JSF, which also runs fine.

After some digging around I found that I seem to have stumbled upon [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814557/tomcat-resource-annotations-api-annotation-stops-working-in-tomcat-7). Does anyone have resolution for that?

Comment: That could be anything. I'd suggest to fix the lack of logging first so that you have hands at the full stacktrace. As to the concrete problem, my first guess would be a failed EL expression evaluation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In the end I was able to locate the erod by adding logging statements and catching NPEs manually (cranking up the log levels of JSF and Tomcat did not help). I added my findings to my question (could not post a decent link from my phone, would be grateful for an edit).

Comment: Any chance of different(maybe versions) jars that reside in Tomcat 6/7 ?