# @Resource annotation not working while injecting DataSource in Tomcat Web Container

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-2.2, tomcat8

I'm developing a small Web App and using a lightweight Tomcat Web Container 8.5.4, JSF 2.2.9, and MySql.

In OrdersBean class, I am trying to use @Resource annotation to inject DataSource

```
@ManagedBean(name="orders")
@SessionScoped
public class OrdersBean {

   //resource injection
   @Resource(name="jdbc/tcomdb")
   private DataSource ds;

   public List<Orders> getOrderList() throws SQLException {

       if(ds == null)
           throw new SQLException("Cannot retrieve Data Source ds");

       //get database connection
       Connection con = ds.getConnection();
       //...
   }
```

However Tomcat Web Container is not injecting datasource and throwing NullPointerException.

But if I try to get DataSource object in a traditional way by context lookup service it works perfectly.

```
//resource injection not working, getting manually.
public OrdersBean() {
    try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/tcomdb");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
  <description>MySQL Datasource example</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/tcomdb</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>

<!-- JSF mapping -->
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

MySql DataSource configuration in context.xml

```
<Context>
   <Resource name="jdbc/tcomdb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="root" password="passwd" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tcomdb"/>
</Context>
```

I suppose dependency injection works in Tomcat Web Container since release of ver. 6 / 7 as seen in the changelog : http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html

Can anyone confirm ? If Tomcat does support then whats going wrong in my code / config ?

Also I want to know how tomcat web container works internally to create DataSource object in both cases: Dependency Injection and Context Lookup?

Please explain.

Comment: What servlet version do you specify in web.xml?

Comment: How are you initializing `OrdersBean`? And what is the default cdi configuration? `all`, `annotated`?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Servlet version is 3.0 as required for jsf 2.2.9

Comment: @maress in JSF ManagedBeans is invoked by JSF LifeCycle Process. OrdersBean class have a default No-arg constructor. And I haven't configured any default CDI configuration.

Comment: So you want to use the injected resource in the constructor? Or even in the class level declaration of a variable?

Comment: And jsf managed beans are **not** cdi related, and it is not java-se related (unless it can be reproduced in a class with a main and only imports from the jdk)

Comment: There is no use, but due to 'bad formatting (lack of indentation), it looked like you had it at class level variable declaration. So I was misguided, sorry (and at the same time, not sorry). And is your 'OrdersBean' annotated in any way to be a 'managed bean'? That to is not visible from your code (hence the comment by someone above). Your reply adds some explanation, but that should be visible in the code ([mcve])

Comment: @Kukeltje What's the point in using injected resource at variable declaration level? Resource injection enables to inject any resource available in the JNDI namespace into any container-managed object, such as enterprise bean, or a managed bean. And as you see in the code OrdersBean class, am using DataSource in getOrdersList() method to retrieve Orders resultSet. But my question still remains unanswered as why injected DataSource not getting initialized?

Comment: yes of course OrdersBean is declared as a Session scoped ManagedBean ....have updated the code. And moreover I think its not jsf problem but Web Container's support problem, as I have mentioned in the question that am able to retrieve DataSource using context.lookup() method .

Comment: The fact that direct lookup works does not mean it is automatically a container problem. Might be that you used the wrong name, or missed making it a managed bean. But since the latter is not the problem then try https://www.google.com/search?q=tomcat+%40resource+Annotation+inject+in+managedbean+jsf&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab  and read e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814557/tomcat-resource-annotations-api-annotation-stops-working-in-tomcat-7 And it does not seem cdi related (I don't see any cdi annotations)

Comment: @Kukeltje after doing enough research on stackoverflow and google I have put the question here, and still working out. By saying problem might be at web container is just a logical thought, not conclusion. And yes @ Resource is Common Annotations as defined in JSR 250, not CDI, thanks.