# @Resource annotation doesn't work in Tomact 10.0.10

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

Recently I tried Tomcat 10.0.10 and when trying to inject the connection pool as a JNDI resource find out that the `@Resource` annotation doesn't work.

Then I tried obtain it programmatically by creating a `InitialContext` and it worked. Initially I thought it was only for the java:comp/env/jdbc so I tried with a simple bean like below and tried to inject it with the `@Resource` annotation it didn't work again. When I try to obtain it programmatically by creating a `InitialContext` and it works. Then I check whether the `@PostConstruct` or `@PreDestroy` annotation works and found out that they also don't work.

```java
package lk.ijse.test.tomcatdbcp;
    
public class Something {
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>

    <Resource name="bean/Something" auth="Container"
              type="lk.ijse.test.tomcatdbcp.Something"
              factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
              />

</Context>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app metadata-complete="false" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
         version="5.0">

    <resource-env-ref>
        <resource-env-ref-name>bean/Something</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>lk.ijse.test.tomcatdbcp.Something</resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>
</web-app>
```

```java
package lk.ijse.test.tomcatdbcp;

import java.io.*;

import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import jakarta.annotation.Resource;
import jakarta.servlet.http.*;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.*;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

@WebServlet(name = "helloServlet", value = "/hello", loadOnStartup = 1)
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private String message;

    @Resource(name= "java:comp/env/bean/Something")
    private Something something;

    @PostConstruct
    public void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("Does it work?");
    }

    public void init() {
        message = "Hello World!";
        try {
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
            Something lookup = (Something) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/bean/Something");
            System.out.println(lookup);
            System.out.println(something); // null
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        // Hello
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

To reproduce the same issue, I created a sample repo here: https://github.com/sura-boy-playground/play-with-tomcat10
(Complete code can be found there)

At first, I had used `javax.annotation.Resource` annotation, so I thought that was the reason because of the `javax.*` to `jakarta.*` namespace change. Then I tried it with `jakarta.annotation.Resource` but the result was same.

**I tried the same application with Tomcat 9.0.41 plus `javax.*` namespace, it works perfectly.**

**Is there any extra stuff that I need to do on Tomcat 10.0.10 to enable these annotations?** I dug the Tomcat 10 documentation but I wasn't able to find out any thing related to my issue.

I found out that there was a similar case in Tomcat 7 previously, but I don't like that kind of workaround now.
[Tomcat @Resource annotations API annotation stops working in Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814557/tomcat-resource-annotations-api-annotation-stops-working-in-tomcat-7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare the scope of your `jakarta.annotation` dependency as `provided`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you have two copies of `jakarta.annotation.Resource` (one in the *common* classloader and one in your application's classloader), the two classes are different. The `InstanceManager` will look for fields annotated with the *common* classloader's copy of `@Resource`, while the `something` field is annotated with your webapp's copy of `@Resource`.

**Edit**: this problem was fixed in Tomcat 10.0.17 (cf. [changelog](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_10.0.17_(markt))), 9.0.59 and 10.1.0-M11.

**Remark**: You will have the same problem in Tomcat 9.0 if you use Java 11 or later. Before Java 11 the `javax.annotation.*` classes where included in the JRE. Servlet containers are required to look in the *bootstrap/JRE* classloader **before** looking in the webapp classloader (overriding `javax.*` classes is a breach of Java's licence), therefore Tomcat would never find the additional copy of the classes.

Comment: Awesome and thank you very much. I was debugging the `DefaultInstanceManager` class just before you posted your answer and the watch expression that I set up for `method.isAnnotationPresent(annotation)` kept giving me false for the `@PostConstruct` while within the servlet it kept returning true, I was wondering what was going there until you come up and clear the idea with two class loaders. Once again thank you very much for the clarification. You saved my day!